# Propel 1.6 cannot access a combined condition even though it is created

Tags: symfony-1.4, propel

When I create a conditon on a much larger query as I do in the function below I cannot then refer to the combined 'category_condition' later on.

Does anyone understand why?
Is this becuase I am creating the condition inside a USE block? And if so is there a way around this?

I get the following error:

```
Cannot combine unknown condition 'category_condition'
```

when I try to do this:

```
 $query->combine(array('domain_condition','category_condition'),'and','category_domain_condition');
```

after creating the condition thus:

```
$query = $this->createCategoryConditionMSC($query, $cats);


 protected function createCategoryConditionMSC($query, $cats)
    {
        //Use methods return query object not alter it so need to catch this and then reassign at end of method.
        $catQuery=$query->useMscdbCategoryStoryLinkQuery();

            $count=0;
            $condsArray=array();
            foreach($cats as $catId)
            {
                $count++;
                 $catQuery->condition('cat_cond_'.$count, 'MscdbCategoryStoryLink.CategoryId = ?', $catId);
                 $condsArray[]='cat_cond_'.$count;
            }


             if(count($condsArray)>0){
                 $catQuery->combine($condsArray,$this->getCategoryCombine(),'category_condition');
             }

        $query=$catQuery->endUse();

    return $query;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be that because I was creating the 'category_condition' condition within the useMscdbCategoryStoryLinkQuery() Block propel cannot then find the condition because I am not within that use block when I try to combine 'category_condition' with another condition.
I didn't find a propel query based solution to this and in the end used a piece of custom written sql.

It is popssible to combien useXXXQuery() blocks using ->_or() as shown in the docs here: http://propelorm.org/documentation/reference/model-criteria.html
but I needed more complex combinations and combinations of combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I am documenting this for myself.  `->condition()` is less flexible than `->addCond()` when it comes to conditions across tables.  I prefer to avoid `->condition()` in favor of `->addCond()` for this reason.

http://sandbox.propelorm.org/e78c98e